# Error while returning SUM values from MySQL with QT

Tags: c++, mysql, qt

Considering the following table:

```
    ID       : int
    Quantity : smallint
    Price    : float(5,2)
```

I tried to run the following *query*:

> SELECT ID, SUM(Quantity * Price) FROM test GROUP BY ID;

As expected, this was executed correctly in MySQL Workbench however, the same did not happen in Qt.

Having the table filled with the following content:

```
 | ID  | Quantity |  Price |
 |  1  |     3    |  1.00  |
 |  1  |     3    |  2.00  |
 |  2  |     3    |  3.00  |
```

And with the following implementation in Qt:

```c
    qDebug() << "Running...";
    QSqlQuery query(myDB);

    query.prepare(" SELECT ID, SUM(Quantity * Price) FROM test GROUP BY ID;");

    if(!query.exec())
        throw "Error";
    else{
        qDebug() << "Size: " << query.size();
        while(query.next()){
             qDebug() << query.value(0).toInt();
             qDebug() << query.value(1).toFloat();
        }
    }

    qDebug() << "End!";
```

The result is:

```
    Running...
    Size: 2
    End!
```

So even though the size returned is 2, the cycle is never run.

Oddly when I change the **Price** variable to *int*, the problem disappears.

Comment: It's not typo error. It was a error writing the post.

Comment: Does it do anything to alias the column name for `SUM(Quantity * Price)` maybe `SUM(Quantity * Price) AS Value`

Comment: It didn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
query.prepare(" SELECT ID, SUM(Quantity * Price) FROM teste GROUP BY ID;");
```

Looks like you typo'd your table name 'teste'

Comment: Error while writing the post. That's not the cause. As a Portuguese, i converted it to English :|

Comment: Is there a value.toShort()? If I recall correctly that is the c++ type equivalent of SMALLINT

Comment: You may want to add some more debugging, first make sure query.next() is returning true as expected, if not, debug the state of query and see if there is anything unexpected.

Comment: That's the problem. Although the size of the results obtained in the query is 2. The **first** query.next() is always false.